Text color in MudBlazor
For color theme in MudBlazor we have a variety of settings: Primary, Secondary, Warning, etc.
We can also configure text colors, like: ErrorContrastText, InfoContrastText and others.
But when I try to set color to text it takes color from non-text colors. E.g., I define text like that: <MudText Color="Color.Info">, I have overrided color for InfoContrastText, but for some reason it takes color of Info.
Is there a way to change text color without changing MudBlazor's CSS classes?
